# can i CNiButton forced to front on CDialog object

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am using both Visual Studio 2012 Update 5 and Measurement Studio 2013 on a
Windows 7 Professional SP1 (64-bit edition), with a MFC C++ (no CLI) project.

I am having an issue with a National Instrument CNiButton object (like CButton)
displaying on a CPropertyPPage object (part of CFormView object). Currently placed
in a Frame. At runtime this control is not viewable. I have verified at design
time that the Visible property is true. I create it a Design time.

I am wondering it somehow it is behind the frame.

Is there a method to bring it Frontmost if needed or someway I can do this at
Design time. If I have to get a CWnd* via GetDlgItem() method, I know how to
do that. If so, will I have a method forward to force to the front??

If I have this all wrong, please let me know what I have missing. Please don't
force me to create at runtime (unless I must to get this to work).

National Instruments people are truly helpless on this subject, since they only
listen to the .Net folks now...

maddog

Comment: This could be anything. What about a [mcve]?

Comment: I would use a Spy++ tool to see if (1) that button exists (it creation could fail for whatever reasons); (2) it has WS_VISIBLE style and (3) it is covered by another control. Each of these will require different fix.

Comment: I found my answer. It was because for some reason, I can't fathom, National Instruments has no method for dealing front|back etc. So once I deleted the GroupBox that apparently was eclipsing it, it worked fine. I could then recreate the GroupBox and all was lovely. Sorry for creating another what ended being a simple solution.

Comment: It is even simpler! This is useful to anyone who works with National Instrument Products such as Measurement Studio and is still using MFC & C++ over .Net technologies:
If you see your (any) NI Control is missing and enclosed in a GroupBox,
just edit the .rc file (be very careful) move the line of the offending Group Box for the appropriate dialog being displayed to after the missing control(s). Save and recompile your project. Voila! your controls are now visible.